# adding a "navigate Back" and "navigate Forward" buttons in django templates

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to add a btn in my navbar.html in django-templates, and every time client clicks it, he navigates to page previous to what he in on, and also "naviaget Forward" if clicked other button.

how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JS:

```
 <button onclick="history.back()">Go Back</button>
 <button onclick="history.forward()">Go Forward</button>
```